# Qt | C++ connect not being triggered

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-connection

I'm trying to play with basic signal/slot in C++.

Here is my **Network-Manager**, which will trigger the event:

```
class NetworkManager : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NetworkManager(QApplication* application);
    void OnFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
    ...
signals:
    void OnReceived();
};
```

And in **Display-Manager**, this class will receive the event:

```
class DisplayManager : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DisplayManager(QApplication *app);
    void ChangeWallPaper();
public slots:
    void ReceiveData();
};
```

And I'm trying to connect from another class:

```
Manager::Manager(QApplication *application, NetworkManager networkManager, DisplayManager displayManager)
: networkManager(application),displayManager(application) {
    ...
    connect(&networkManager, &NetworkManager::OnReceived, &displayManager, &DisplayManager::ReceiveData);
}
```

And in these class's implementation:

```
void DisplayManager::ReceiveData() {
    std::cout << "being called" << std::endl;// to check if this is being called
}

void NetworkManager::OnFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    OnReceived(); // to trigger
}
// OnReceived() not implemented as it just a signal
```

What am I missing here? Why is the *ReceiveData* function not being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [the solution](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/gnome-mua-desktop/blob/6751c03664cccfb5feb8cf0195bb87f114d745a5/gmd-app/Manager.cpp#L7-L18) :

```
Manager::Manager(QApplication *application,
                 NetworkManager _networkManager,
                 DisplayManager _displayManager)
        : networkManager(application)
        , displayManager(application)
{
    ...
    connect(&networkManager, &NetworkManager::OnReceived,
            &displayManager, &DisplayManager::ReceiveData);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider your `Manager` constructor...

```
Manager::Manager(QApplication *application,
                 NetworkManager networkManager,
                 DisplayManager displayManager)
    : networkManager(application)
    , displayManager(application)
{
    ...
    connect(&networkManager, &NetworkManager::OnReceived,
            &displayManager, &DisplayManager::ReceiveData);
}
```

You pass the addresses of locally scoped variables `networkManager` and `displayManager` to `connect`.  The connection will be destroyed as soon as those temporary variables go out of scope when the constructor completes.

Try passing `networkManager` and `displayManager` either by reference or pointer.

Comment: i'm passing them as pointer, and they don't work.. you have pasted my code, just doing some indentation

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your last comment.  In the code you supplied the constructor for class `Manager` accepts a `NetworkManager` and a `DisplayManager` by *value*.  Perhaps you could show the class definition for `Manager`.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Are you sure the code in your question is the *real* code?  Looking at it again it shouldn't be possible to pass `NetworkManager` or `DisplayManager` by value if they inherit from `QObject`.

Comment: yeah, this is **real code**. *your solution doesn't work*, **you've just copy pasted my code with indentation**. can you tell what's the difference between the code i posted and you did, except that indentation part ?

Comment: I pasted you code into my answer to provide some context for what I thought was the problem.  But, if the class definitions for `NetworkManager` and `DisplayManager` are as shown then I don't see how the `Manager` code provided can even compile.  Again, please show the class definition for `Manager` and show how you are using it.  Better still, provide a [mcve].